# Angular If Statement

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular and I would like to know how to do something similar to an if statement.

I am using ionic to build my web app and have an xml feed coming in with a thumbnail which is shown like this "{{post.thumbnail}}"

Here is what I tried to do to show an alternative image if the image is empty.

```
<div ng-hide="{{post.thumbnail}} == null">
  <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
</div>
<div ng-hide="{{post.thumbnail}} != null">
  <img src="img/dining.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-if` OR `ng-show/hide`. OR Another approach could be to do if-else in Controller. This will also avoid duplication of `<div>` if there are more than one condition to be checked.

Controller:

```
if $scope.post.thumbnail != null {
  $scope.imageSrc = $scope.post.thumbnail
} else {
   $scope.imageSrc = 'img/dining.jpg'
}
```

and in template:

```
<div><img src="{{imageSrc}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

```
<div ng-if="post.thumbnail">
  <img ng-src="{{post.thumbnail}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
</div>
<div ng-if="!post.thumbnail">
  <img src="img/dining.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-hide="post.thumbnail == null"><img src="{{post.thumbnail}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>
<div ng-hide="post.thumbnail != null"><img src="img/dining.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, while most of the comments work, this is the most practical and what I was looking for. Tx! Btw I ended up getting rid of the div's and use the ng-hide in the image tags :)

Comment: @Jason:Use === and !== for comparison in js

Comment: @Muhsin Use the extra `=` if it is required to compare including type